# Aliassing into a directory that uses mod_rewrite: 404 not found?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, virtualhost, mod-alias

When I `Alias` into a directory with a .htaccess file with `RewriteRules`, I get a "404 Page Not Found" message.

In my vhost configuration I have the following:

```
Alias /foo 
<Directory "/home/andrejovich/public_html/foo">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

So that's fairly standard.

In /home/andrejovich/public_html/foo I have a .htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|css|img)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~andrejovich/foo/index.php/$1 [L]
```

The notion is that addresses such as "http://example.com/foo/bar/baz" Just Work(tm).

This is true if I go to my home dir directly, as in "http://example.com/~andrejovich/foo/bar/baz": my index.php is executed and I get the page I expect -- so I know that my index.php is working.

If I omit anything after "foo", my index.php generates a default page for me, which also works for both "http://example.com/~andrejovich/foo" and "http://example.com/foo" -- so I know the alias is working.

However, if I go through the alias and have the /bar/baz parts there, it fails:

"http://example.com/foo/bar/baz" ==> 404. How come? How do I fix it?

Comment: The `Alias` directive takes 2 parameters; the first is a URL path, and the second is a filesystem path. Your example is missing the filesystem path. So, as is, I don't think the Alias is working. In fact I think Apache would throw an error and not start. Is your example missing something?

Comment: I don't see any problems with the mod_rewrite portion. I've tried something as close as possible to that on my computer and it all Just Works(tm). What are you getting in your Apache error_log?